# as I can I know the value del@Html.DropDownList (....) selected in the view? in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

I need to know which item is selected from dropdownlist in view 
how do I know from @Html.DropDownList (....) 
because I need to use the value "text" of dropdownlist in a query "if (...)"

example:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
    <span>Enviar una Notificacion a...</span><br />
    <span>@Html.DropDownList("Value", ViewBag.ComboEnviar as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Seleccione una opción")</span>

 </div>
```

....

```
 @if (@Html.DropDownList(...).SelectValue == 0)
 {
      <label for="descripcion">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.nameUsuario)</label>
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<span>@Html.DropDownList("Value", ViewBag.ComboEnviar as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Seleccione una opción")
```

when you will check in DeveloperTool you will find it will render as

```
<select id="Value" name="Value">...</select>
```

so it is Clear you can use its `Id="Value"` as `JQUERY Selector`

```
if($('#Value').val()==0)
{
 //Do some Magic Stuff Here
}
```

Still Confusion!! Comment Below it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do but you certainly don't want to perform the check on the result of the `DropDownList` method.  You probably want to find the selected item in the `ViewBag.ComboEnviar`.  Note this will only work when the page is rendered (server-side), it won't do anything client-side if the value is changed. For that you'd need some JavaScript.

```
@{
    var selectList = ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ComboEnviar).ToList();
    var selectedItem = selectList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Selected && Value == 0);
}


<div class="editor-label">
    <span>Enviar una Notificacion a...</span><br />
    <span>@Html.DropDownList("Value", selectList, "Seleccione una opción")</span>    
</div>

@if (selectedItem != null)
{
    <label for="descripcion">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.nameUsuario)</label>
}
```